# Derivatives in mathematica

Tags: derivatives

If we consider a function like $G(\tau_i,\tau_j)$ and its first and second derivatives as $\partial_i G(\tau_i,\tau_j)=\dot{G}(\tau_i,\tau_j)$ and $\partial_i\partial_j G(\tau_i,\tau_j)=\ddot{G}(\tau_i,\tau_j)$, how can one generates all the following total derivatives using mathematica? 
$$ (\partial_i-\partial_j)(\partial_k-\partial_l)(\dot{G}_{ij}\dot{G}_{kl} e^{f(G_{ij})})
$$
in which $f$ is a general function of $G_{ij}$'s. This derivatives generate many terms and that is why I would like to use mathematica but I am not sure how to generalize the definition of $D[g(x),x]$ in mathematica for any index of the G-function.

Comment: Try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The [xAct package](http://www.xact.es/) for mathematica might be useful for this.